# In SQLite how to insert a new column into s table with values of a column in another table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

In SQLite I have two tables, T1 and T2. They have exactly the same number of records.
I can run the following command to create a new column in T1

```
alter table T1 add column t2_col;
```

Suppose T2 only has one column. How do I replace the t2_col's content with T2's row by row (by rowid essentially).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery to read the value from the corresponding `T2` record:

```
UPDATE T1
SET t2_col = (SELECT t2_col
              FROM T2
              WHERE T2.rowid = T1.rowid)
```